# Background coloring

Tags: graphics, color, options

I find the syntax of Background not clear. For instance in an example found in an old question

```
Grid[Table["g", {4}, {7}], 
 Background -> {None, 
   None, {{{2, 3}, {1, 3}} -> LightRed, {{3, 4}, {4, 7}} -> 
     LightBlue}}]
```

the elements from the line 2 to 3 and column 1 to 3. I would naturally think of `{{2, 3}, {1, 3}}` as a matrix imposing the coloring of the cells `{2, 3}`
to  `{1, 3}` whichever be the order. That is two cells on the third column not the square `{{2, 3}, {3, 3}}` as effectively done. I do not understand the two `None`. To resume could some one gives a better explanation than the one which is in the Mathematica documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for `Background` in `Grid` is `Background -> {columns, rows, elements}`. I will be referring to these as the columns list, the rows list, and elements list respectively. Example of coloring rows and columns:

```
bg = {
   {LightRed, LightBlue, LightGreen}, (* columns *)
   {LightYellow, LightOrange}, (* rows *)
   None
   };

data = Table["g", {4}, {7}];
Grid[data, Background -> bg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The image shows that the first element in the list `columns` gives the color of the first row, the second element in `columns` gives the color of the second column, and so on. Columns with no specified color remain transparent. Not white, but transparent. There is a difference, because when both the row color and the column color is specified for a certain element, then they appear to blend.

If you only specify one element instead of a list, then that color is used for all elements:

```
bg = {
   LightRed,
   None,
   None
   };

data = Table["g", {4}, {7}];
Grid[data, Background -> bg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can think of `{columns, rows, elements}` as three layers since they can all be specified separately and blend if they overlap. `None` specifies that the particular layer is transparent. Which brings us to this example:

```
bg = {
   None,
   None,
   {{3, 4}, {4, 7}} -> LightPurple
   };

data = Table["g", {4}, {7}];
Grid[data, Background -> bg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `elements` list uses the syntax `{{rowStart, rowEnd}, {columnStart, columnEnd}}`. All the rows and columns spanned by the rows `rowStart` to `rowEnd` and the columns `columnStart` to `columnEnd` are given a certain colors. You can put 2x2 matrices like this in a list if you want to specify several blocks. Note that the purple is not blended with any other color since the `columns` list and the `rows` list are `None` (i.e., transparent).

There is yet another syntax to keep track of. The colors will be repeated cyclically if you wrap the columns list or the rows list in another pair of brackets:

```
bg = {
   {{LightRed, LightBlue}},
   None,
   None
   };

data = Table["g", {4}, {7}];
Grid[data, Background -> bg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And, finally, you can also specify how rows and columns are to be colored by their indices:

```
bg = {
   {1 -> LightRed, 4 -> LightBlue},
   None,
   None
   };

data = Table["g", {4}, {7}];
Grid[data, Background -> bg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice answer & examples. You could add a link to the [documentation section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html#13842222) as a reference on how to get this information yourself. (Then all information of my answer would be fully contained in yours and easier to find in the future)

Comment: @Mathe172 Thanks. It's enough to have it here in the comments I think, I would only add that the documentation for [Background](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html?q=Background) also writes about this, under Generalizations & Extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the documentation of `Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) (more specifically the section [Options->Background](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html#13842222)), we can infer the following syntax:

```
Background->{<Columns>[,<Rows>][,<Cells>]}
```

The specifications for `<Columns>`/`<Rows>` can be:

- A single color to apply to all columns/rows
- A list of colors for the individual columns/rows
- A list of rules for specific columns/rows

For `<Cells>`, the specifications are in the form of a list of rules `{<Columns>,<Rows>}-><Color>` where `<Columns>`/`<Rows>` can be a column/row index or a range thereof (specified by `{<start>,<end>}`)

In all cases, omitted values default to `None`.